# Set default value in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an xml file as following and when the filePath2 is null or empty I want the value of that to be of filePath1's value. Is there a way in which I can achieve this through JAXB.

```
<file filePath1="C:/filePath">
   <subFile name="Test">
      <filePath2></filePath2>   
   </subFile>
<file/>
```

I don't want to hardcode the default value. If the value for filePath2 is null or blank("") I want to set the filePath1 attribute as the value of 'String filePath'. Is there a way to do it via a setter in JAXB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using plain Oracle JAXB I only see the possibility to implement that using an [javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html). 
Implement that interface in your model class and perform the necessary checks in the `afterUnmarshal(..)` method.

There you can access the value of `filePath1` and set (if necessary) it to `filePath2`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your inputs, at the end I opted for a simpler solution; to update the setter where filePath2 is being called.
The JAXB part -

```
String filePath2;
@XmlElement(required = true)
public void setFilePath2(final String file) {
    this.filePath2= file;
}
```

Where filePath is used -

```
if (filePath2 == null || filePath2.isEmpty()) {
   setFilePath2(getFilePath1());
}
```

If you come across a bettr yet simple solution let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use annotations, than this should do the trick

```
...
private String foo;

@XmlElement(defaultValue="bar")
public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
...
```

Comment: That will hard-wire the default value to `"bar"`. It won't dynamically read `../../@filePath1`